# How to get user id using SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

We are using SharePoint online. would like to set a variable with user's ID.

The login name of the current user is returned as `i:0#.f|membership|yourEmailadress`.

Is there any way we can get the user id?

Comment: Are u using Workflow to get user_ID?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by 'set a variable' - is this in a workflow, or a page, or what?

Comment: yes sharepoint designer workflow and am trying to set a field with user id

Comment: In that case see my answer below... it's a little bit long winded but it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the ID is available in the same way in SPO as it is in on-prem, but logically I would use this approach:

1. Have a script running on a PC somewhere that periodically (once a day should be enough) grabs a list of all users in the tenant - it's also a good idea when using a list like this to have it delete all the existing entries to avoid duplicates
2. Script uploads the Claims-Based Auth username form and associated user ID to a list in SPO for each user it finds
3. Workflow gets the ID by selecting the item from the list where it finds a match on the Claims-Based Auth username form

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
var userID = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
```

Update for workflows:

In workflows User profiles is available as a data source. Pick user profiles, ID and then match the list item so that Account name equals 'Created by' (as string)

Comment: If it's a page that's a nice elegant solution, but no dice if it's a workflow variable... hasn't been clarified tho.

Comment: Sorry it is in a sharepoint designer workflow